# iframe not displaying video in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an `iframe` which will play clicked videos.

I tried

```
var iFrameWindow = document.getElementById("xFrame");
iFrameWindow.src = videoSrc;
```

here the `videoSrc` is a var which will contain the video source.

Here is an example `videoSrc`:

```
http://www.youtube.com?v=123sd
```

I also tried jQuery version.

Both works perfectly working in Chrome, but in IE8 its saying

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame

What might be the issue?

Comment: that will be something like www.youtube.com?v=123sd

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving the error message associated with the [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) header disallowing framing of the page. You should be receiving a similar error in other browsers, not just IE.

In your example, you are using the non-embed URL for YouTube. All pages on YouTube except the embedded player pages send the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header, to prevent framing.

The embed URL follows this convention:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/abc123
```

And the view on YouTube URL follows this convention:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc123
```

If you wish to frame a YouTube video, you will have to use the embed URL.

Comment: is there a way we can change the header coming from the site? 
the videos that i am showing are hosted in some other intranet, so it might not have the embed like youtube has

Comment: @vignesh Unless you control the server sending the response headers, there is no way to disable them. They are a security feature designed to prevent click-jacking and other attacks.